# some difficulties in OAuth 2: Should I save authorization code or just access token?

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0

Note: This is not about coding, but about the approach itself.

I'm making a client for a website which uses OAuth 2.. Since this is my first time using oauth 2 I have some problems in understanding the approach. As I know until now:

I should send my access token with every request. To get this access token in the first time I send user to the website and after login I get an `authorization code`. Then I send this `authorization code` and my `client_id` and `client_secret` to get the `access token` and finish.

until here every thing is fine. But in the next application execution, I don't know what to do. I don't want to ask user to login every time. But how can I know my access token is still valid?
should I save my authorization code and request a new access token again?

I request a non-expiring access token, but to refresh the access token I should send some `refresh_token`? What is this? Should I send the old access token as this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@Eugenio's answer is correct.

To answer your specific questions

**But how can I know my access token is still valid?** 
The access token comes with an expiration time, usually one hour. The other way is to try to use it and catch the 401 status if it's expired.

**should I save my authorization code and request a new access token again?**
No. The authorization code can only be used once. You can either request a refresh token, save that, and then use that to get subsequent access tokens, or you can repeat the authorization process, which depending on the provider, may or may not require user involvement since the provider will know that the user has previously authorized your app.

**I request a non-expiring access token, but to refresh the access token I should send some refresh_token?** 
There is no such thing as a non-expiring access token. You use a refresh token in order to obtain a new access token.

**What is this [refresh token]?**
It's a string that your app can pass to the provider to say "hey it's me again. Remember a while ago user xxxxx, granted me, application yyyy (client id), the authority to do aaaa and bbbb (scopes) on his behalf, even when he's not present. Well I'd like to do some now so please can I have an access token".

**Should I send the old access token as this?**
No. Once an access token has expired it has no use or significance at all.

Answer (score 3):

The `access_token` you get from the authentication site is good to call *their* APIs, not your app. You should keep it if you need to call them back eventually in your app.

For example, if your users are authenticating with Facebook, the `access_token` you get will be good to call Facebook's endpoints.

OAuth2 is in essence an *authorization* protocol: the user is granting you permission to access his/her information on their behalf.

A commonly used, and useful side effect of this process is to treat these users as "authenticated" because, presumably, you can only get an `access_token` from a legitimate user.

It is then up to your site to establish a session with them. You would do this exactly as you would if you were authenticating the user yourself, likely after you successfully retrieved the `access_token` using the code. (or sometimes after retrieving the user profile from the Authorization Server, another common technique).

You can browse a sample that does this on the .NET platform here: https://docs.auth0.com/aspnet-tutorial (this is configured to work with our own OAuth server, but the principles are generic).

The code this sample relies on is available here: https://github.com/auth0/auth0-aspnet